# Windows Phone 8 lens app overlays

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8

I'm writing a Windows Phone 8 lens app in C# and would like to overlay text such as the current time and location but I can figure out how to draw text over the image.

I'm using the PhotoCamera class as the source for a VideoBrush of the Canvas background as the  viewfinder.

I've searched the internet regarding overlays when using the PhotoCamera class but couldn't find anything.  Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i haven't done any #WP8 specific camera work / lens dev however in #WP7 you need to create a WriteableBitmap and then do specific operations on it. like in this case overlaying timestamp.

have a look at http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/ as it provides many extension methods
download it using nuget / package manager http://nuget.org/packages/WriteableBitmapEx

Comment: Thanks for that.  Unfortunately visual studio won't let me install the WritableBitmapEx library, something about the version being incompatible.  Anyway I have tried to use the WritableBitmap class but calling the Render method, however it doesn't produce an image when calling invalidate, however it does produce an image if I call invalidate but don't call Render, any ideas?

Comment: download the correct version using nuget (package manager in vs 2012) http://nuget.org/packages/WriteableBitmapEx

Comment: I've tried that already but get the following error from Nuget 
"Install-Package : Could not install package 'WriteableBitmapEx 1.0.5.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that 
targets 'WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework."

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working, I had to download the source from the repository and recompile it.